# Total of true and false in current time

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have got this XML document. Is there way how to sort the nodes by ascending time and by brand and then count how many cars (samples), true and false was in this time from start time (always the lowest time in the group)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<trade>
    <car time="1950" brand="audi" trend="true">
    </car>
    <car time="1200" brand="renault" trend="true">
    </car>
    <car time="1000" brand="audi" trend="true">
    </car>
    <car time="2800" brand="renault" trend="true">
    </car>
    <car time="2000" brand="audi" trend="true">
    </car>
    <car time="1500" brand="renault" trend="true">
    </car>
    <car time="1900" brand="audi" trend="false">
    </car>
    <car time="2300" brand="audi" trend="false">
    </car>
    <car time="2100" brand="renault" trend="false">
    </car>
</trade>
```

Wanted result in HTML

[image: Results after XSLT]

Comment: Show what you've tried already

Comment: I have grouped the nodes with `for-each-group` by brand, then sorted by time with `perform-sort`, but then I do not know how to grouped the true and false...

Comment: You can try something like `//trade/count(//car[@time <= 1950 and @brand="audi"]/@trend[.="true"])` - just use variables instead of `1950`, `"audi"` and `"true"` values

Comment: Ok, but what if I can have different times? Can you please do it a xslt fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to include what you have got next time in the question text. If you already know how to group and how to sort you can then easily process the sorted sequence and take the subsequence until each item and check the count of the items with a certain trend as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">


  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="trade">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="car" group-by="@brand">
          <h2>{current-grouping-key()}</h2>
          <table>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Total of samples</th>
                      <th>Time</th>
                      <th>Total of TRUE</th>
                      <th>Total of FALSE</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <xsl:variable name="sorted-cars" as="element(car)*">
                  <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
                      <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(@time)"/>
                  </xsl:perform-sort>
              </xsl:variable>
              <tbody>
                  <xsl:for-each select="$sorted-cars">
                      <tr>
                          <td>{position()}</td>
                          <td>{@time}</td>
                          <xsl:variable name="car-group" select="subsequence($sorted-cars, 1, position())"/>
                          <td>{count($car-group[@trend = 'true'])}</td>
                          <td>{count($car-group[@trend = 'false'])}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </xsl:for-each>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQ1

Comment: Sorry that I have got so much not so good question. But I am interesting in one last thing. The time in example is in milliseconds. Is there way how to do with XSLT the `Total of samples``Total of TRUE``Total of False` per one second? For example in one second (1000-1999 ms) for audi I have 3 samples, which 2 is true and 1 is false and another data for another second (2000-2999 ms) and etc.? So the result will be like here https://jsfiddle.net/1wq7oofw/2/ ? I do not know how to specify that I want data just for one second.