# Total of true and false per second

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I am refering to this question [Total of true and false in current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49873285/total-of-true-and-false-in-current-time/49875486#49875486). I want to know if it possible to have the same result like in the link, but the total true and false will be per second.

The wanted result in

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>audi</h2>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Total of samples per second</th>
               <th>Time</th>
               <th>Total of TRUE</th>
               <th>Total of FALSE</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>1950</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>2300</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <h2>renault</h2>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Total of samples per second</th>
               <th>Time</th>
               <th>Total of TRUE</th>
               <th>Total of FALSE</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>1500</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>2800</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for ideas

Answer (score 0):

So instead of outputting the sorted sequence directly you additionally want to group by the `@time idiv 1000`:

```
  <xsl:template match="trade">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="car" group-by="@brand">
          <h2>{current-grouping-key()}</h2>
          <table>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Total of samples</th>
                      <th>Time</th>
                      <th>Total of TRUE</th>
                      <th>Total of FALSE</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <xsl:variable name="sorted-cars" as="element(car)*">
                  <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
                      <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(@time)"/>
                  </xsl:perform-sort>
              </xsl:variable>
              <tbody>
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="$sorted-cars" group-adjacent="@time idiv 1000">
                      <tr>
                          <td>{count(current-group())}</td>
                          <td>{current-group()[last()]/@time}</td>
                          <td>{count(current-group()[@trend = 'true'])}</td>
                          <td>{count(current-group()[@trend = 'false'])}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </xsl:for-each-group>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQ1/1

Or you don't need to sort but use `group-by="@time idiv 1000"`, perhaps the sorting the groups by the `current-grouping-key()`.